# Deployment Groups - You do not have permissions to register targets. Contact your release manager to grant permissions

Tags: security, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

Coming across an issue in Azure DevOps Server (On-prem) 2019 Patch 1.1 where when 1 person creates a 'Deployment Group' under a project - no one else can register a target, as they see an alert stating: 'You do not have permissions to register targets. Contact your release manager to grant permissions.'

[image]

In this particular case I was explicitly made an administrator of the deployment group as a last ditch effort and I still see this message.  I am a collection admin and have every right under the sun as far as I can tell under the main security tab under the collection.

[image]

[image]

What is the correct way to grant user permissions to avoid this alert and allow everyone to register targets for a deployment group in a project?

Comment: So even with the explicit administrator role on the deployment group, you still get the error?

Comment: That is correct, I still get the error even w/ an explicit administrator role on the deployment group.  The only person who can register a target is the person who created the deployment group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a deployment group in a project, it will actually create a deployment pool at the organization level.

**Org Level:**

[image]

**Project Level:**

[image]

You likely need to configure the deploy pool security at the root level (so it inherits) since it is empty by default:

[image]

Comment: I had this exact issue and it does appear that adjusting the (blank, never configured) security as the org level may have helped.  no amount of grants on the deployment groups at the project level seemed to take